# Python3 - asyncio versus requests - performance

Tags: python, python-requests, python-asyncio

I have recently started looking at *asyncio* in Python 3 and wanted to test it out. I am not able to understand why *asyncio* code is running slower than *threading* based code.

It is quite likely that I have not understood how *asyncio* exactly works so appreciate any comments.

*Asyncio* based code below:

```
import asyncio
import requests

async def main():
    for i in range(10):
        task = asyncio.create_task(foo('https://catfact.ninja/fact'))

async def foo(api_url):
    x = requests.get(api_url)
    print(x.json().get('fact'))

asyncio.run(main())
```

When I run the above code using `time python3.11 asyncio_test.py` on my linux VM, I get the below output

```
$ time python3.11 asyncio_test.py
The Maine Coon cat is America's only natural breed of domestic feline. It is 4 to 5 times larger than the Singapura, the smallest breed of cat.
One reason that kittens sleep so much is because a growth hormone is released only during sleep.
The smallest pedigreed cat is a Singapura, which can weigh just 4 lbs (1.8 kg), or about five large cans of cat food. The largest pedigreed cats are Maine Coon cats, which can weigh 25 lbs (11.3 kg), or nearly twice as much as an average cat weighs.
A cat named Dusty, aged 1 7, living in Bonham, Texas, USA, gave birth to her 420th kitten on June 23, 1952.
Phoenician cargo ships are thought to have brought the first domesticated cats to Europe in about 900 BC.
A kitten will typically weigh about 3 ounces at birth.  The typical male housecat will weigh between  7 and 9 pounds, slightly less for female housecats.
The average litter of kittens is between 2 - 6 kittens.
In Siam, the cat was so revered that one rode in a chariot at the head of a parade celebrating the new king.
The name "jaguar" comes from a Native American word meaning "he who kills with one leap".
The normal body temperature of a cat is between 100.5 ° and 102.5 °F. A cat is sick if its temperature goes below 100 ° or above 103 °F.

real    0m9.308s
user    0m0.551s
sys     0m0.039s
```

However, if I run the below *threading* based code using `time python3.11 requests_cats.py`

```
import queue
import threading
import requests

def foo(q):
    x = requests.get('https://catfact.ninja/fact')
    q.put(x.json().get('fact'))

q = queue.Queue()

for i in range(10):
    t = threading.Thread(target=foo, args=(q,))
    t.start()

for i in range(10):
    print(q.get())
```

I get the below output and it's significantly faster as evident from the output

```
$time python3.11 requests_cats.py
Cat's urine glows under a black light.
Cats lose almost as much fluid in the saliva while grooming themselves as they do through urination.
Cats can be taught to walk on a leash, but a lot of time and patience is required to teach them. The younger the cat is, the easier it will be for them to learn.
A queen (female cat) can begin mating when she is between 5 and 9 months old.
In 1987 cats overtook dogs as the number one pet in America.
A cat's nose is as unique as a human's fingerprint.
Cat bites are more likely to become infected than dog bites.
People who are allergic to cats are actually allergic to cat saliva or to cat dander. If the resident cat is bathed regularly the allergic people tolerate it better.
Cats respond most readily to names that end in an \ee\" sound."""
The largest cat breed is the Ragdoll. Male Ragdolls weigh between 12 and 20 lbs (5.4-9.0 k). Females weigh between 10 and 15 lbs (4.5-6.8 k).

real    0m2.098s
user    0m1.239s
sys     0m0.047s
```

I was expecting that both the asyncio and the requests (with queues) will give me approximately the same execution time.

Comment: ayscnio one is stil normal syncronous one, it is not performing as u think, request is sync bound, so this thus make ur code sync one. use `aiohttp` with asyncio and see the result

Comment: Test with httpx vs requests ;)

Comment: Indeed, the `requests` call inside the `async` function will still be synchronous, meaning `async` will mainly sit around and wait for it to complete. Switch to a properly `async` HTTP library.

Comment: Your code is not fully asynchronous. You are just wrapping a regular method in async. Replace `requests` with something asynchronous like `aiohttp`.

Comment: you would need asyncio to delegate to `loop.run_in_executor(None, foo, 'https://catfact.ninja/fact')`  to get a similar performance without `Thread` and `Queue`

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of aiohttp, requests-futures, and httpx but wanted to actually see if this can be done just using asyncio. So, it appears that I must use low level functions like `loop.run_in_executor`. I thought that `asyncio.create_task` is meant to run coroutines concurrently as asyncio tasks?